# MuleSoft: How to refer to file nested under resource folder

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb, cloudhub

I am doing a Mulesoft project by Mule-Anypoint studio.

Recently I categorized my resource files (xml, csv, xsl..) into nested folders under "resources" folder. (ex: resources/FlowResources/flowA/resource-a.csv) and updated the components to corresponding path. Everything works fine but when deploying to CloudHub throws following error:

> Your application has failed with exception com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.v3.dto.DeploymentException: Unable to load FlowResources/flowA/resource-a.csv. It works fine again if I move the files up front to resources folder.

Is it some kind of limitation when we deploy to CloudHub? Cannot locate file in nested resource folders?

Comment: Are you talking about a `resources` folder at project root, or the `src/main/resources` folder? Also by " It works fine again if I move the files up front to resources folder." What do you mean by that? You moved the files into `src/main/resources/resource-a.csv` instead of `src/main/resources/FlowResources/flowA/resource-a.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Your project hierarchy should look like as follows :[image: MuleProject]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Basically, you need to update your .classpath file.

inside .classpath

> resource entry exists -  < classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/" >
>
> need toupdate or add new entry of it it  as path="src/main/resource/myfolder".